# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: All possible solutions have been tried :(

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

On the line at which this exception is occurring, It's already in session scope i.e. session is available for proxy class yet this exception is occurred.

controller class code in which error has occurred :

```
  try{
    SessionFactory sessionfactory = MyFactory.getSessionFactory();
              Session s = sessionfactory.openSession();
    EmployeeDetails e = getEmployee(p_id);
        DailyDataDetails d = new DailyDataDetails();
            d.setEmp_id(p_id);
            d.setEmp_name(p_fname+" "+p_lname);
            d.setPayable(pay);
            d.setRate(Float.parseFloat(txtrate.getText()));
            d.setSpindles(Integer.parseInt(txtSpindle.getText()));
            d.setHour(hr);
            d.setMin(min);
            d.setWork_date( java.sql.Date.valueOf(select_date.getValue()));


                 s.beginTransaction();
                 e.getDdd().add(d);
            s.save(e);
            s.getTransaction().commit();
            s.close();
             Notifications notiBuild = Notifications.create()
                        .title("Value Added")
                        .text("Value added sucessfully")
                        .graphic(node)
                        .hideAfter(Duration.seconds(5))
                        .darkStyle()
                        .position(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

                notiBuild.darkStyle();
                notiBuild.show();

                loadData();



    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
```

Exception :

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: models.EmployeeDetails.ddd, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:582)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:201)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.write(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:392)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.add(PersistentBag.java:297)
at empman.FXMLAddValueController.toAddData(FXMLAddValueController.java:174)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Here is my model class :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="eid"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
private Collection<DailyDataDetails> ddd = new ArrayList<DailyDataDetails>();

public int getEid() {
    return eid;
}

public void setEid(int eid) {
    this.eid = eid;
}

public Collection<DailyDataDetails> getDdd() {
    return ddd;
}

public void setDdd(Collection<DailyDataDetails> ddd) {
    this.ddd = ddd;
}
```

Points to be Noted :

=> Exception occurs on the line  e.getDdd().add(d) in FXMLAddValueController, but this line already in the scope of hibernate session

=> I have used fetch= FetchType.Lazy because i don't want child data

=> I want specific Solution and the reason why this happening.

=> It's a desktop app so i have only hibernate.cfg.xml.

=> I'm using One-to-Many mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the transaction for  getEmployee(p_id);  is already closed. the queries should be in the same transaction.